# Integração com a autenticação do Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, autenticação, integração

Levando em consideração um site baseado em Wordpress e um sistema de gestão que roda no mesmo domínio, porém com recursos de autenticação totalmente independentes, penso em integrar  a autenticação do Wordpress com o sistema de gestão, ou seja, ao logar pelo Wordpress, terei acesso automaticamente no sistema de gestão através de um link no próprio menu do Wordpress.

Minha necessidade é de ter os dados do usuário disponíveis no sistema de gestão, como id, nome, sobrenome entre outros.

Se um usuário tentar acessar alguma página interna restrita do sistema de gestão sem autenticar, o sistema deve redirecioná-lo para a autenticação do Wordpress.

Gostaria de ideias para esta integração e ideias de implementação técnica.

Comment: Já pensou em autenticação por serviço (Google, Facebook, Yahoo, OpenID...)? É prático pois bastaria a você consumir as respectivas APIs e seguro tanto quanto os desenvolvedores dessas soluções podem proporcionar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível apontar as tabelas `wp_user` e `wp_usermeta` para outras no mesmo DB usando as [seguintes constantes em `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Custom_User_and_Usermeta_Tables):

```
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', $table_prefix.'my_users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', $table_prefix.'my_usermeta' );
```

A questão é que essas outras tabelas tem que ter a [mesma estrutura que o WP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Database_Diagram):

[image: user tables]

Relacionado: [*Make website login work on WordPress too*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21106556/1287812) e [SSO / authentication integration with external 'directory service'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/8887/12615).

Comment: Obrigado pela ideia, na verdade mata o problema. Vou estudar sim este método. Levando em consideração o custo x benefício, acredito ser a forma mais prática. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Reporto-me à minha experiência numa solução que trabalhei. No meu caso específico o sistema de autenticação era independente do Wordpress e do sistema de gestão. No Wordpress um plugin construído para o efeito autentica o utilizador no sistema de autenticação e no sistema de gestão acontecia o mesmo.

Após a autenticação bem sucedida alguns dos campos do utilizador eram actualizados no Wordpress pois é necessário para alguns plugins que possa instalar que irão requer alguma dessa informação do utilizador para não falar do próprio Wordpress.

O sistema de autenticação separado tem muitas vantagens pois separa os serviços e coloca especialização em cada um dos serviços. Consegue ainda centralizar credenciais para além de muitas outras vantagens.

Com a utilização de `WebServices` e com a gestão de `TOKENS` por exemplo, foi possível 
gerir as acções dos utilizadores de forma a que estes apenas se autentiquem uma única vez, apesar de utilizarem os vários serviços disponíveis.

Comment: Perfeito. Não dá para falar de integração de sistemas sem ao menos começar citando WebServices :)

Comment: Excelente sua solução conceitual. Na verdade, seria mesmo ideal trabalhar com webservices, mas acredito não seria interessante no meu caso por conta do custo x benefício, pelo menos pelo projeto em questão. Agora, tecnicamente falando, a resposta abaixo do @brasofilo atende bem a necessidade de forma rápida... porém mediante as respostas e comentários, estou inclinado a deixar autenticação independente mesmo, como você mencionou.

Comment: @DanielAccorsi verdade é mais caro manter um serviço de autenticação separado, mas o que percebo hoje é que a autenticação deve mesmo ficar separada... falando claro para empresas, pois o crescimento em utilizadores pode ser exponencial o que no futuro pode colocar problemas.

Comment: @chambelix, engraçado como houve duas soluções praticas aqui. Temos informações ricas nesse tópico. Cada caso atendendo uma necessidade específica de complexidade. É bem isso que você falou agora, e outra: no meu caso WP seria para gestão de conteúdo, e o sistema seria para gestão da empresa, melhor deixar separado mesmo, ou seja, são usuários distintos.